# Boolean adds the object instead of subtracting it (only in certrain objects which are like the ones that worked)

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I extracted a lot of Cylinders with the boolean modifier. It worked really well except for these 5 cylinders (red) that are still there. Instead of subtracting the cylinder it adds it (picture 3). It even already adds the cylinder before I apply the modifier.(picture 2)
When I try the same process on them they either add the cylinder or don't work at all.
How can I subtract the last ones??? Is there another way of subtracting the object then boolien?

[image: cylinders]
[image: before applying boolean]
[image: added cylinder]

Comment: Are you sure it's not set to Union. In the first image, although I can see the modifier, I cannot see the target object selected. And also whether the cylinder in question is the one it's being performed on or not. If all the other things are correct, try moving the cylinder by like 0.00001 in some direction. Usually works.

Comment: Yess all the settings are the same: Difference, Object (which i select), exact.
Your tip with moving the cylinders worked for one of them but not for the others...
Any other solutions???

Comment: btw.... you won't get smooth shading with the boolean method. but if that is not a problem for you then ok fine :)

Comment: what do you mean with "smooth shading"? Is that important for 3D printing?